# Why does mis-spelling true/false not raise a compiler error in the online Elm editor (as opposed to elm-repl)?

Tags: elm

The following Elm program is supposed to print 10 if the mouse button is pressed and 20 if it is not pressed, but it always prints 20 (when running it at http://elm-lang.org/try) :

```
import Mouse
import Text (asText)
import Signal (map)


nextVal : Bool -> Int
nextVal down = 
  case down of
    true -> 10
    false -> 20


main = map asText (map nextVal Mouse.isDown)
```

The cause for this behaviour is a simple mis-spelling - if you replace `true` with `True` and `false` with `False`, everything works as expected.

But why don't I get a compiler error for this? I'd have expected something similar to the error message I get from the elm-repl: `Could not find variable 'true'`

*UPDATE*
In fact (as hinted at in the answer by @Apanatshka), this code also works in the REPL, so Elm behaves consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have to look into why elm-repl gives that error.

When I try this code on [elm-lang.org/try](http://elm-lang.org/try) it always gives 10. The code you've provided is valid Elm code. When you write a lowercase name in a `case`-`of` pattern, that name is considered a pattern variable. It will match anything and bind what it matches to that name. So your `nextVal` function will try to match a boolean with the given patterns, in the order given. It starts with the first pattern, which is a single pattern variable, therefore it always matches. There it stops searching, because the pattern matches, therefore 10 is always returned.

Perhaps you would prefer to use an `if`-`then`-`else`?

```
nextVal down =
  if down
    then 10
    else 20
```

One last thing: When you're just matching an enumeration like `Bool` it probably doesn't seem useful to have these pattern variables. Just to show that it can be useful, I wrote a little example with a singly linked list:

```
type SLList a =
  Cons a (SLList a)
  | Nil
-- a list of 1,2,3 would look like: Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Nil))

removeSurroundingElements : SLList a -> SLList a
removeSurroundingElements l = 
  case l of
    Nil -> Nil
    Cons _ Nil -> l -- `_` means ignore
    Cons _ (Cons _ Nil) -> l
    Cons e1 (Cons e2 (Cons e3 tail)) ->
      Cons e2 (removeSurroundingElements tail)
-- removeSurroundingElements (Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Nil))) == Cons 2 Nil
-- removeSurroundingElements (Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 (Cons 4 (Cons 5 (Cons 6 Nil))))))
--   == Cons 2 (Cons 5 Nil)
```

Comment: That explanation makes perfect sense. And in fact, it also works in the REPL - I had made a stupid mistake when running it inside the REPL.